# How to render vuejs component on sibling submit

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I have the following code

```
<body>
   <div class="content" id="app">
      <file-management></file-management>
      <attachment-list></attachment-list>
   </div>


   <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
```

FileManagement component code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <button type="button" @click="storeList()">
            Save
        </button>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            storeList: function () {
                axios.post('/list', this.data, config)
                    .then(() => {
                      // on save I want to be able to load the table again that is found in AttachmentList component  
                    });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

AttachmentList component code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <tr v-for="attachment in attachments" :key="attachment.id">
            <td>{{ attachment.name }}</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                attachments: []
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getList() {
                axios.get(`/list`)
                    .then((data) => {
                        this.attachments = data;
                    });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

What I want to do is that I want to be able to load the table of the list when I click save in the other component (after the post request has completed). How will I be able to achieve this?

Comment: When you click save or after the POST request has completed?

Comment: After the post request has completed. Inside .then()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to have your `FileManagement` component emit an event which the parent can listen to, then trigger the `AttachmentList#getList()` method.

For example

```js
// in AttachmentList
methods: {
  async storeList () {
    await axios.post('/list', this.data, config)
    this.$emit('list-updated')
  }
}
```

and in the parent template

```html
<file-management @list-updated="$refs.list.getList()"></file-management>
<attachment-list ref="list"></attachment-list>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response Phil.
Would this be the cleanest way to do it?
I really don't mind restructuring the code to approach a cleaner way.

Comment: @CEJ that's kinda up to you. This looks clean to me and a component's methods represent part of its API so there's nothing wrong with calling methods via `ref`. I suppose the other approach is to use some sort of shared state like Vuex but that's probably overblown for what you're doing

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would proceed.

- create a parent component for the siblings.
- add a boolean data member (flag) to it with the status of the clicked button.
- emit a signal from `FileManagement` when the button is clicked.
- catch this signal in the parent component to set the flag.
- pass this flag to the `AttachmentList` component as a prop.
- use this flag inside a `v-if` to show / hide the the table.

Comment: Thank you for the response Anuvrat.
Would you be able to put an example?